# Finding Closest Available Non-0 or NA value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel dataset that looks something like this:

```
Variable    1.2018  2.2018  3.2018   ... 
  A            4       5       8     ... 
  B            4       5       n.a   ...
  C            4       0       5     ...
  D            4       n.a     9     ...
```

On a separate sheet I have a summary table that extracts numbers from this dataset using an index match function.

However, I am hoping for my function to not take on 0 or n.a values. Take for example, ideally, I would wish to compare growth between A and B at 3.2018, variable B contains n.a and wouldn't be very useful. In this case I would rather then compare between A and B at 2.2018 instead.

```
Variable    3.2017  3.2018   Growth 
  A            5       8      60%
  B            5       n.a    #VALUE


Variable    2.2017  2.2018   Growth 
  A            3       5      66%
  B            4       5      25%
```

In the other case, say I were comparing between C and D. If I were to compare them at 3.2018, I would have no problems because they do not contain 0 or n.a values. However if I were to compare them at 2.2018, then I would want the formula to take the values from 1.2018 instead.

In the above cases, I would also like to know when it is the case that the values do not come from the 'ideal' time frame.

I tried to do an "if" before the index match but in the case of the first example it will only change the number of B and not A. It also does not work if I have 2 or more 0's or na's in a row.

Comment: 1. how does your index match formula looks like? || 2. you'd mention "compare between A and B".. does it means you actually have 2 outputs (2 separate formula) ?

Comment: Exactly! I edited the question to give a simplified version of the table I will produce.

Comment: can you share the formula you tried here -->  "I tried to do an "if" before the index match" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do an IF() function, wherein you check if either of your 3.2018 values are either 0 or #N/A (assuming these are actually the excel value of #N/A, and not a string representation like "n.a.")... if either are true, use the 2.2018 value otherwise use the 3.2018 values

```
=IF(  OR(IFNA(D3=0, TRUE),   IFNA(D2=0, TRUE)),   C2=C3,   D2=D3)
```

[image: example solution]

Comment: Hi thanks for this however, I was looking for something with less manual input as the actual table is a lot bigger.

Comment: I still believe this answer is an exact solution for the question you've described. I'm not sure what "manual input" you're referring to, because you can drag-and-copy the equation to the entire column - Column F, in my example. The snippet of code I posted should be inserted into cell F3.